# If construct in hashmap.put call

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a variable of type Hashmap`<String,Integer`>.

In this, the Integer value might have to go some manipulation depending upon the value of a flag variable. I did it like this...

```
Hashmapvariable.put( somestring,
    if (flag_variable) {
     //manipulation code goes here
     new Integer(manipulated value);
    } else {
     new Integer(non-manipulated value);
    }
);
```

But I get an error:

> Syntax error on token(s), misplaced
>   constructs.

at the Hashmapvariable.put call.

I also get another error

> Syntax error on token ")", delete this
>   token.

at the final ");" line. But I can't delete the ")" - its the closing parentheses for the put method call.

I don't get this. What mistake am I doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot place a statement in the method call.

However, one option could be to make an method that returns a `Integer` such as:

```
private Integer getIntegerDependingOnFlag(boolean flag)
{
    if (flag)
        return new Integer(MANIPULATED_VALUE);
    else
        return new Integer(NON-MANIPULATED_VALUE);
}
```

Then, you can make a call like this:

```
hashmap.put(someString, getIntegerDependingOnFlag(flag));
```

Answer (score 7):

```
 new Integer(flag_variable ? manipulated value : non-manipulated value)
```

Does the trick

Edit: 
On Java 5, I suppose you can also write

```
hashmap.put(someString, flag_variable ? manipulated value : non-manipulated value)
```

due to auto-boxing.

Comment: If the alternate expressions are not both of type int then the semantics become "interesting".

Answer (score 0):

This isn't scheme, so if statements don't evaluate to a value. You'll have to use a tri-if-thing (the name escapes me for some reason right now) or create a function, as someone else said.

Comment: Name: it is a ternary operator, or more precisely, a comparison operator (there could be other kinds of ternary operators, although I haven't seen them in popular languages...).